# How to copy an SKNodes with children

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, gameplay-kit

How do i copy an `SKTileMapNode` or an `SKNode` containing two or more `SKTileMapNode`.

Structure is:

- BackgroundNode (empty)

  - SKTileMapNode
  - SKTileMapNode

I would love todo the following inside of my Scene:

```
guard let background = self.childNode(withName: "BackgroundNode") else {
    return
}
background0 = background
background1 = background.copy() 
self.addChild(background1)
```

This results in a not visible something. The Nodes are copied but i still can't see anything and the values of the SKTileMap are not copied properly to the copy. For example the tileSize is not applied.

How do i manage to get a copy of my `BackgroundNode`?

Answer (score 0):

You should override`copy(with:)` method of `SKNode` class with your own implementation, to be able to copy with `SKNode` its children.
But you can simply do something like this:

```
guard let background = self.childNode(withName: "BackgroundNode") else {
    return
}

let backgroundCopy = SKNode()

for child in background.children {
    backgroundCopy.addChild(child)
}
addChild(backgroundCopy)
```

Comment: Of course if you need "hard" copy of every child, you can try something like this: `backgroundCopy.addChild(child.copy() as! SKNode)`